# Controlling Axios Get Calls in a loop in Node

Tags: node.js, axios

my code is running amok.

I have a script that reads a json file and iterates over it, using the key "Id" as the api value in an axios get call.  The data from the response is saved to a directory.

What I would like to happen is for one value to be read from the source file, that call be made, that data be saved and then the next iteration.  I would love for this to happen in a nice, boring synchronous manner.

What actually happens is that all of the iterations go out immediately, overwhelming the server causing a 400 error back "too many requests"

I have tried to use setInterval at various points in the code.

I have also tried using axios-extensions to throttle the requests.

I've tried to use a block to check if the loop has run and if it has, not run it again.

I've even put in a function to check is the data file exists and to only try to pull it if it does not.  It seems to ignore that as well.

Nothing I've tried has made any impact.

I'm guessing that the 400s are causing unfulfilled promises to retry and that I'm just not handling them properly.

What I don't understand is why I can't get the requests to slow down.

I know it's probably something dumb but I have several days of beating my head on the wall trying to get it working.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
function getAPI(activeURL, callId) {
    
    let idPath = (detailDataPath + activeURL)

    //This if seems to be ignored.  It makes the call even if the file exists.
    
    if (fs.existsSync(idPath)) {
        // path exists
        console.log(activeURL, "saved");
      } else {

    //I've tried to wrap the get in a setInterval

    instance.get(activeURL, () => {

        })
        .then(resp => {
            apiData = (resp.data);
   
            try {
            (async () => {
                saveDetail(apiData);
            })();
                
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(resp.status);
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log("error", callId);
        })
    }
}

function loupe(activeURL, callId) {

    //I've set this value to various values.  If calls are made more than 500ms    apart, I will get 400 errors

    setInterval(function (){
        getAPI(activeURL, callId);
    }, 1000);
}

function mainLoop(sourceData) {

    fs.readFile(sourceData, "utf8",  (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
        }
        let detailList = JSON.parse(data);

        //I've tried forEach here

        for (let i = 0; i < detailList.length; i++) {

        let activeURL = (detailList[i].Id);
        callId = i;

        //I've tried wrapping this in a setInterval
        loupe(activeURL, callId);
        
        }  
    })
}
function throttle() {
    hasRun = true;
    mainLoop(sourceData)
}

let hasRun = false;

function runOnce() {
    if (!hasRun) throttle();
    console.log("run complete")
}
runOnce();
```

Answer (score 0):

After trying Bluebird and p-Limit I was able to get the api calls with Bottleneck.

It's less than ideal but it does work consistently without 400 errors.